# PHP - Upload file error - Permission denied

Tags: php

i am trying to run this simple php code:

```
<?php

$dir = getcwd()."\uploads\ ";
if($_FILES['myfile']['error'] != 0)
{   
    echo "Error uploading the file: {$_FILES['myfile']['error']}";   
}

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $dir . $_FILES['myfile']['name'])) {   
    echo 'Success!!!';   
} else {   
    echo 'Error.';   
}

?>
```

I am getting this problem:

> failed to open stream: Permission denied in... on line 7 Unable to
>   move ... to ... on line 7

Line 7 is: `move_uploaded_file`

I understand that maybe the problem is with the folder permission, and i need to use CHMODE command.
But i don't understand how to use it and where do i put it in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use slashes `/`instead of backslashes. And check permissions to target dir.

```
$dir = getcwd() . "/uploads/";
```

Comment: Even better to use [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) instead of any hardcoded slash

Comment: @kingkero: not sure. If I know I have (and always will have) linux server, there is no reason to use syntactically longer constant than a direct slash.

Comment: But there may be a time someone else uses your code or your project gets ported onto a windows machine

Comment: thank you, but your solution didn't work for me. How do i check permissions of the dir?

Comment: @user3478552: `chmod` function, see the Manual.

Comment: i tried using this command, with permission 755 and 777 but nothing is working. can it be a problem of a permission in the host?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can call chmod() before the line with move_uploaded_file() for example like this

```
chmod($dir, 755);
```

You can find more information about [chmod() on the documentation sites](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But it didn't help. when i tried it, i got an error chmod(): Permission denied

Comment: That means that the file creator of the php file which executes chmod() doesn`t have permissions to use chmod(). If you`re running it on some web hosting, you may want to contact them. If this error shows on localhost, you may need to create a special user to run PHP.